# Unity create line with gaps in between points

Tags: unity-game-engine, line

I'm trying to create a similar game like Curve Fever with some sort of 'snake' going around with an increasing tail. What I'm trying to achieve is having gaps in between the line once every x seconds.

Currently I'm using a LineRenderer and setting points like this:

```
void Update() {
    if(Vector3.Distance(points.Last(), snake.position) > pointSpacing)
        SetPoint();
}

public void SetPoint(){
    if (noGap)
    {
        if (points.Count > 1)
            coll.points = points.ToArray<Vector2>();

        points.Add(snake.position);

        line.numPositions = points.Count;
        line.SetPosition(points.Count - 1, snake.position);
    }

}

public IEnumerator LineGap(){
    while (enabled)
    {  
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(2f);
        noGap = false;
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(.5f);
        noGap = true;
    }
}
```

With the coroutine above I tried to not create points once every 2 seconds for .5 seconds, but a LineRenderer is made to create a line between every 2 points.

Is there any way to achieve what I'm trying to do? Maybe by using another kind of renderer?

Comment: Have you looked into Vectrosity?

Comment: Sure, there's another way to render lines! Consider [`GL.Lines`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GL.LINES.html). Or for a non-one thickness, you may need to draw quads.

Comment: Use multiple line renderers, one for each segment of the line. Do NOT use low-level rendering functions unless absolutely necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to create a new LineRenderer for each line segment. Your snake would then keep track of an List of LineRenderers. If you make your LineRenderer GameObject a prefab it is easy to spawn it on the fly. Your `Snake` class would look something like this:

```
public class Snake
{
    public GameObject LinePrefab;           //Prefab gameobject with LineRenderer
    private List<LineRenderer> pathList;    //List of line segments
    private LineRenderer line;              //Current line


    private void Start(){
        this.pathList = new List<LineRenderer>();
        SpawnNewLineSegment();

        //Other initialization code
    }

    public void Update(){
        if (!noGap && Vector3.Distance(points.Last(), snake.position) > pointSpacing)
            SetPoint()
    }

    public void SetPoint(){
        if (points.Count > 1)
            coll.points = points.ToArray<Vector2>();

        points.Add(snake.position);

        //Increment the number of points in the line
        line.numPositions = line.numPositions + 1;
        line.SetPosition(line.numPositions - 1, snake.position);
    }

    public IEnumerator LineGap(){
        while (enabled)
        {  
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(2f);
            noGap = false;
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(.5f);
            noGap = true;

            //We are starting a new line, create a new line segment
            SpawnNewLineSegment();
        }

    private LineRenderer SpawnNewLineSegment(){
        //Spawn the gameobject as a parent of this object
        GameObject go = Instantiate(this.LinePrefab, this.transform);
        this.line = go.GetComponent<LineRenderer>();
        this.pathList.Add(this.line)

        //Set the first point on the line
        SetPoint()
    } 
}
```

The only question would be how you want to handle your collision (I assume that is what `coll` means). Does the collision span the gaps or does it leave a hole there? As written it looks like the collider would be continuous (not have gaps).

If you are worried about the performance of spawning new GameObjects at runtime you can create a pool of them on initialization and then just disable them until they are needed.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I eventually figured that I would had to instantiate a new LineRenderer indeed, so it's working now. But since this does answer the question I will accept it as the answer!